# Want to display a maximum of 5 thumbnails

Tags: c#, html, razor, slamdata

Want to show max 5 images in a thumbnails. But It print all images it have.

```
@foreach (var orderline in order.OrderLines.DistinctBy(ol => ol.imageURL))
{
    <img height="40" src="@orderline.imageURL" alt="@(orderline.Listing.Title.Length > 15 ? orderline.Listing.Title.Substring(0, 15) : orderline.Listing.Title)" />
}
```

Comment: Just use `Take()`, so `order.OrderLines.DistinctBy(ol => ol.imageURL).Take(5)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already using some Linq in your code, so just use a little more.  The [Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) method in Linq will do exactly what you want:

```
@foreach (var orderline in order.OrderLines.DistinctBy(ol => ol.imageURL).Take(5))
{
    <img height="40" src="@orderline.imageURL" alt="@(orderline.Listing.Title.Length > 15 ? orderline.Listing.Title.Substring(0, 15) : orderline.Listing.Title)" />
}
```

The `Take(5)` I added at the end means you will only iterate through a maximum of 5 items

Comment: ohh!! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks maccettura. I did :)

Answer (score -1):

change your foreach to a for loop

```
@for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)

  Your code goes here using thing[i]
```

Comment: Then they would have to materialize the collection which might not be what they want to do.  There are ways to do this _without_ materializing the collection.